# How to create indexes on mongoengine EmbeddedDocument?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have Document and EmbeddedDocument. I want to create an index on EmbeddedDocument's field.
Here are example structure and what I have tried.

```py
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, fields


class Parent(Document):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'parent',
        'indexes': [
            'name',
            'child__name',  # throws mongoengine.errors.LookUpError: Cannot resolve field "child__name"
            'child.name',  # does nothing
        ],
    }
    name = fields.StringField()
    child = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Child)


class Child(EmbeddedDocument):
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            'name',  # does nothing
        ],
    }
    name = fields.StringField()
```

Is this even possible to create such index?

Comment: Dot notation is the correct one so `child.name` in `Parent` document should work. I've just tried it in Mongoengine 0.16.3 and it worked as expected. Unfortunately I have no idea why it doesn't in your case.

Comment: Yes, dotted notation is correct. There is a problem with my model - dunno why indexes are not created. Other models works well.